# My program is working, but I don't want overlapping of adjacent pairs. For e.g; if i have 'aaa', the number of pairs should be only 1, not 2

Tags: python, recursion

```
def pairs(message, num_pair, i):
  if i == len(message) - 1:
    return("Number of pairs:", num_pair) 
  else:
    if message[i]==message[i+1]:
      return pairs(message, num_pair+1, i+1)
    else:
      return pairs(message, num_pair, i+1)


def main():
  message = input("Enter a message: \n")
  num_pair = 0
  i = 0
  message, p = pairs(message, num_pair, i)
  print (message, p)

main()
```

---

```
Enter a message: 
aaaa
Number of pairs: 3
```

However, the output should be 2, when you finish comparing two characters and find that they are the same, it should move to the other character from the second one.

Comment: Okay, so what's your question? What problem are you having trying to change the program to work the way you want it to? What don't you understand? What *specifically* do you need help with? ("Fix my program for me" is not a question.)

Comment: I need to be able to move the index to two characters to the right whenever there is an adjacent pair of numbers.

Comment: Right, and do you have some question about that? Do you understand how the code works? Have you worked out how the algorithm has to be changed? What help do you need? You've told us what you need to do but not asked us a question about how to do it, so we don't know what help you need.

Comment: you can remove the pair from the list if the order is not important. If it is then you can copy the string in a temp var. If the string is too large then as @RedX suggested.

Comment: RedX fixed your program, but solving this problem recursively isn't a very good idea. Python has a recursion limit ~1000, so your program will crash for strings longer than that. Obviously this isn't a problem if your task is to learn recursion.

Comment: I understand how it works. It keeps on checking every character with the character next to it. That's why it counts more than 1 pair. So, even if a pair is found, it will check the character next to it with the next one, and so on. How do I increment the index by 2 without going out of range?

Comment: @ therealprashant @ csiz . Yes, I tried incrementing by 2, but for some strings, it says' index out of range'

Answer (score 1):

After detecting a pair skip it completely. This means instead of advancing by 1 char advance the index by 2.

Comment: Yes. But if it does not detect a pair, move it by 1.

Comment: I tried incrementing the index by 2, but for some strings, it will say 'index out of range'.

Comment: @azhar Of course you need to check if your index is still in range before you use it to access the string...